# azure function upgraded blobtrigger to v2 or v3 still gets warning "Cannot Upgrade with Existing Functions"

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, azure-blob-trigger

Ive upgraded my blobtrigger from v1 to v2 and created a new function in azure, the blobtrigger runs smoothly with the new function app set to v2 or v3, created a new project in vs2019 and is set to .netCore 3.1 etc. But in azure i still get the warning message "Cannot Upgrade with Existing Functions".

I even have created a blob trigger from template without any changes in code and published it to a new function app in azure, even then the message still shows.

Does the warning ever go away or is it there just for information? Cant find anything about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it's just a tip for you to refer, no action required. Same as this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915158/cannot-upgrade-with-existing-functions)

Comment: yes ive seen that post, thought that maybe other might have a different answer, I think its just stupid of microsoft to have that as a warning/information when the app is coded to work in v2 or v3... microsoft will not deprecate it for now but will probably do it in the future, setting this to answered... thanks.